# VB ItemTemplate DataBinder.Eval Container.DataItem in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This is the HTML in the VB project that is being ported to a new C# app:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="DG1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" width="850" AllowSorting="True" OnSortCommand="LawSortEvent" ShowFooter="true" onItemDataBound="LawDG_ItemDataBound" FooterStyle-Font-Bold="True" >
  <Columns>
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="afecategory" SortExpression="afecategory" HeaderText="Code" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="transdate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" SortExpression="transdate" HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="company" SortExpression="company" HeaderText="Vendor" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="description" SortExpression="description" HeaderText="Desc" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="systemtype" SortExpression="systemtype" HeaderText="System" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="apinvoice" SortExpression="apinvoice" HeaderText="AP Inv" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
  <asp:BoundColumn DataField="amount" SortExpression="amount" DataFormatString="{0:C}" HeaderText="Total" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  />
    <asp:templatecolumn headertext="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
      <itemtemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton id="btnViewInvoice" runat="server"
          ImageURL="/images/glass2.png" 
          OnCommand="dgViewInvoice" 
          CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "apinvoice") %>' 
          commandname='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "vendornum") %>' 
          AlternateText="View Invoice" 
          Visible='<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "systemtype") <> "GL") %>' 
        />
      </itemtemplate>
    </asp:templatecolumn>
  </Columns>
</asp:Datagrid>
```

My issue is with the ImageButton - I don't know how to write that in C#, because I'm not really sure what it is trying to do.

The closest I found to explaining some of this was [What's the deal with Databinder.Eval and Container.DataItem?](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2004/07/20/what-s-the-deal-with-databinder-eval-and-container-dataitem.aspx), but I've been trying different ways of changing my text to make this work for the last 30 minutes with no success.

Everytime I change the text, the error message changes to what I tried to do differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rock.

I figured it out.

### Skadoosh!

```
<asp:templatecolumn headertext="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
  <itemtemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton id="btnViewInvoice" runat="server"
      ImageURL="/images/glass2.png" 
      OnCommand="dgViewInvoice" 
      CommandArgument='<%# Eval("apinvoice") %>' 
      commandname='<%# Eval("vendornum") %>' 
      AlternateText="View Invoice" 
      Visible='<%# Eval("systemtype") != "GL") %>' 
    />
  </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatecolumn>
```